# Disco SSD MacBook Air

Tags: macos

Quiero formatear todo mi disco a los ajustes de fábrica, me ha creado volúmenes y un contenedor y no puedo instalar Boot Camp porque me dice que es insuficiente el espacio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bievenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Quieres formatear todo el disco para no tenerlo más particionado?  ¿Quieres hacer dos nuevas particiones con el espacio mejor distribuido? Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/186551/edit) explicando mejor lo que quieres.

Comment: Quiero formatear todo el disco, quiero eliminar ese contenedor y dejar todo el espacio sin volúmenes, al instalar Boot Camp me dice que es insuficiente el espacio

Comment: Entonces, supongo que estás partiendo de una instalación en limpio (Clean Install) y que ya tienes copia de seguridad de tus datos. Si no es así, haz copia de seguridad de todos tus datos y luego ejecuta un `Clean Install`. En el proceso de instalación, ejecuta `Disk Utility` y borra todas las particiones. Así se quedará el disco sin particionar y se hará la instalación nueva. Luego restauras los archivos, instalas Boot Camp y lo que quieras instalar, mientras el espacio te de.

Comment: Que formato debo de ponerle al disco ssd, AFPS o Mac plus con registro, he formateado todo el disco pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo, un volumen con el sistema instalado que solo tiene 23gb de espacio desde a donde tengo que formatear el disco desde CMMD + R o desde alt option al arrancar el sistema?

Comment: Lo mejor es que hagas una instalación nueva desde cero. En el proceso de instalación habrá un momento en el que podrás ejecutar `Disk Utility`, desde ahí selecciona borrar todas las particiones. En cuanto al sistema de archivos que debes elegir, [puedes leer este artículo](https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT208033) con algunas recomendaciones.